# Duration read as date in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am reading an Excel file into Power BI that contains a duration column in the form of, for example, HH:mm:ss 0:02:20. When this Excel file is read in power bi duration column is read as date. for example, 0:02:20 will be read as 31-Dec-99 12:02:20. my question is how can I keep the duration to 0:02:20 in power bi?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure step setting column type is using duration

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type duration}})
```

Comment: I tried this it gave me errors.

Comment: I got it. I just extracted minutes and seconds from date.